# jquery: possible to create GET string with nested arrays using serialize()?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page with 3 forms on it.

To create a valid get(or post) data str with each form as a nested array nested arrays.

psuedo-code for what i want (just don't know how to wrap them in nested arrays..):

```
var data_str = $('#form1').serialize() + $('#form2').serialize() + $('#form3').serialize();
$.ajax(.....
```

desired output on processing file:

```
print_r($_GET);
/*
{
    ['form1'] => .....nested array here..
    ['form2'] => .....nested array here..
    ['form3'] => .....nested array here..
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a javascript pro but I've built a solution and it works, enjoy:

```
function mutliple_forms_to_data_str(array_of_form_ids){
    var multidim_data = {};
    $.each(array_of_form_ids, function(index,id) {
        var forms_data = $('#'+id).serializeArray();            
        var htemp = {};
        $.each(forms_data, function(index,val) {
            htemp[val.name] = val.value;
        });
        multidim_data[id] = htemp;
    });    
    return multidim_data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get({
data:{
   form1:$('#form1').serialize(),
   form2:$('#form2').serialize(),
   form3:$('#form3').serialize()
},

//other options
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen, but this just creates 3 GET/POST values and no nested arrays. There are serialized strings instead of nested arrays...

Answer (score 0):

Use array push, to do that

but honestly you best use one form no need for all three of them unless is last resource.
or simply.

```
var data_str = {
     'form1': $('#form1').serialize(),
     'form2': $('#form2').serialize(),
     'form3': $('#form3').serialize(),
    }
```

PHP would read them fine as a tree like array,

You might have to use `serializeArray();` instead

Comment: php reads this like:` Array
(
    [form_1] => 'data_str1'
    [form_2] => 'data_str2'
    [form_3] => 'data_str3'
)`

Comment: it's 3 forms because it's part of a webapp, and the forms can be submitted separately.

Comment: interesting getting close. serializeArray(), gives `[0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => inputnamehere
                    [value] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => inputnamehere
                    [value] => 2011-03-06
                )
`  So I'm losing my KEY => VALUE relationship

Comment: ok, got it working will post my solution shortly for other's reference.